# How to change Pyomo solver interface

Tags: python, pyomo

Using Pyomo, instead of creating a file that is to be sent to the solver, I want to start using the Python interface of solvers that are compatible (i.e. CPLEX or GUROBI). What is the default solver interface when not specified, and how can someone specify the wanted solver interface within this code?:

```
opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')
results = opt.solve(model, options= solverOptions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create the direct solver explicitly:

```
from pyomo.environ import SolverFactory
solver = SolverFactory('gurobi_direct')
```

or with using the "`python`" IO option to the Gurobi "metasolver":

```
solver = SolverFactory('gurobi', solver_io='python')
```

Comment: Will both solutions produce the same result: direct solver will be used?

Comment: Yes. Both routes return a `pyomo.solvers.plugins.solvers.gurobi_direct.GurobiDirect` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SolverFactory('gurobi', solver_io='direct')`

Comment: Sorry, I get the following message while trying with gurobi.
`RuntimeError: Attempting to use an unavailable solver.

The SolverFactory was unable to create the solver "gurobi"
and returned an UnknownSolver object.  This error is raised at the point
where the UnknownSolver object was used as if it were valid (by calling
method "solve").

The original solver was created with the following parameters:
 solver_io: direct
 type: gurobi
 _args: ()
 options: {}
`

Comment: Are the gurobi python bindings installed for the python environment that you're using with Pyomo? How did you install Pyomo?

Comment: Gurobi is installed. I installed Pyomo using Anaconda packages. Then, I ran command line `conda config --add channels http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi` and `conda install gurobi` on my Windows environnement cmd (following the indications of http://www.gurobi.com/downloads/get-anaconda). Are you suggesting that my Python Gurobi installation might be incomplete?

Comment: I think that for some reason, Pyomo is not able to find your Gurobi installation. There might be a linking missing. What happens when you open a python terminal and try to `import gurobipy`?

Comment: After pressing enter, it doesn't give me any error, but it doesn't tell me anything. I can input an other line. However, I still have the same issue while solving the problem. Can it be because another solver name must be provided (ex: "PythonGurobi")? I also suspect my own installation of Python Gurobi. Let me try to find if it is really installed.